# I've Lost 2FA in PhpMyAdmin, how can i reset it?

Tags: phpmyadmin

My phone died last night, so, sadly, I've lost all of my 2FA codes and now I cannot connect into my PhpMyAdmin.

Is there a way to disable/remove 2FA by using the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the U2F(2FA) by deleting the row or the data in the phpmyadmin table `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig`

```sql
DELETE FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__userconfig` WHERE username='root';
```

See my comment on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15433#issuecomment-521383779